# Ошибка, связанная с Case-sensitive при сборке кросскомпилятора, используя crosstool-ng в Cygwin

Tags: кросс-компиляция, cygwin, gcc

Возникает ошибка:

> `$ /opt/ng-crosstool/bin/ct-ng build
> [INFO ]  Performing some trivial sanity checks
> [ERROR]  Your file system in '/forbuild/.build' is *not* case-sensitive!
> [00:01] / make: *** [build] Error 1`

Когда я пробую собрать кросскомпилятор в unix-оболочке Cygwin, запущенной под Windows с помощью скриптов crosstool-ng. Вот [ссылка](http://pastebin.com/bP3ecceZ) на скрипт .config

Пробую, например, так в `\etc\fstab`:

Вот [здесь](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-specialnames.html) вроде как бы даётся решение проблемы, но видимо из-за непонимания чего-то на англ. Я возможно не так что-то делаю.
Я пробую, например, в `etc\fstab` добавить строку и перезапустить Cygwin:

```
C:/forbuild /forbuild ext3 binary,posix=1
```

Но всё равно такая же ошибка при запуске `/opt/ng-crosstool/bin/ct-ng build`

причём если набираю `mount` пишет следующее:

> `C:/cygwin/bin on /usr/bin type ntfs (binary,auto)
> C:/cygwin/lib on /usr/lib type ntfs (binary,auto)
> C:/forbuild on /forbuild type ntfs (binary)
> C:/cygwin on / type ntfs (binary,auto)
> C: on /cygdrive/c type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
> D: on /cygdrive/d type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)`

Comment: Т.е. реестр вы подправили? `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\kernel\obcaseinsensitive` содержит 0? И раздел, разумеется, NTFS?

Answer (score 1):

по приведённой в самом вопросе [ссылке](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-specialnames.html#pathnames-casesensitive) рекомендуется присвоить значение 0 ключу реестра

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\kernel\obcaseinsensitive
```